# "Previous" / "Next" tab navigation system (AngularJS / AngularJS Material)

Tags: angularjs, tabs, navigation, angular-material

I am developing some content display in various tabs, using `Angular.js 1.5.x` and `AngularJS Material 1.1.0`.

I  first used the Angular Material `md-tabs` system like this : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs.

Unfortunately, our users do not use them as they do not seem to understand they are tabs. I am now working on a new, more obvious, tabs system :
[image: new tab navigation system I want to implement, with "previous" / "next"]

I haven't found any  Angular material way **to create this "previous/next"-based tab navigation system**.
Do you know where I could look ?  It does not need to be Angular Material, any help or lead is welcome :) I want to avoid complexity or custom code if possible, so I want to capitalize on existing frameworks.

Comment: Change the tag from angular to angularJs. Angular is for angular2+

Comment: Thanks @alexKhymenko. Does Angular2+ offer a solution to my issue ?

Comment: @Treebird I'm sorry im more angular2 guy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use mdTabs. You can create a custom button and make them to command the tab by changing the selected tab with:  md-selected

Then hide the tab navigation by md-no-pagination , or by adding display:none to .md-tab css.

eg, for 3 tabs:

```
<div>
  <md-tabs md-selected="tabIndex">
      <md-tab label="tab1">
        tab1 content
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="tab2">
        tab 2 content
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="tab3">
        tab 3 content
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
    <md-button ng-click="back()" class="md-raised">
      Previous
    </md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="next()" class="md-raised">
      Next
   </md-button>
 </div>
```

and controller:

```
  $scope.back = function() {
    if ($scope.tabIndex > 0) {
      $scope.tabIndex--;
    }
  };
  $scope.next = function() {
    if ($scope.tabIndex < 2) {
      $scope.tabIndex++;
    }
  }
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWSRBb?p=preview

Comment: that's... awesome ! I had a feeling Angular Material would allow that, but couldn't figure out how.
Thanks a lot, have a nice day :)

Comment: Hey, is there a way to dynamically set the tabIndex maximum number?  So instead of setting tabIndex<2, can you do something like tabIndex< tabIndex.length?

Comment: Hey @Dave, yes, maybe a tabData.length?